# How to download a file successfully indexed in apache solr?

Tags: tomcat, curl, solr, solrj, solr4

I am able to successfully index a PDF doc using a curl request. But since solr only indexes the doc, and do not host it, I have tried hosting the PDF on tomcat 7 , and tried to index document using following curl command : curl 'localhost:8983/solr/update?commit=true' -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '[{"id":"fileId","url":{"set":"http://localhost:8080/path-to-file/fileName.pdf(doc)

"}}]' . I have put my PDF in examples directory inside tomcat installation directory . This curl command successfully indexes PDF , but is not able to download it, when i click on the link, gives 404 error ! What am i doing wrong, can anybody tell me ?????

Comment: You get an error when you click on the URL you stored in Solr, right? But the problem happens in the browser, not Solr. So, you seem to just have an incorrect URL or unescaped URL. Or trying to access localhost from outside of the same machine. Nothing to do with Solr. If I misunderstood, you may want to clarify the question on exactly where and how the error happens.